# Form children's name attributes overwriting form's own attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

Please accept my apologies for asking which might seem obvious to everyone besides me ...

Is it normal that in the following snippet:

```js
let form;
form = document.getElementById('thing1');
console.log(form.id, typeof form.id);
form = document.getElementById('thing2');
console.log(form.id, typeof form.id);
```

```html
<form id="thing1">
  <input name="id">
  <input name="thing1">
</form>
<form id="thing2">
  <input name="identifier">
  <input name="thing2">
</form>
```

which yields the following console log:

```
<input name="id">         'object'
thing2 string
```

the form's child input (which has a name identical to an existing global attribute of the parent) overwrite's the form's attribute?

I'm using the inputs' names to relate to an external database field names ... and of course 'id' is a very common column name there ....

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: @ksav -- the code is just there illustrate the question ... does the child's `name="id"` attribute indeed overwrite the value of `form.id` with its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on `Element.id` all the time, you can try `Element.getAttribute("id")`:

```html
<form id="thing1">
  <input name="id">
  <input name="thing1">
</form>
<form id="thing2">
  <input name="identifier">
  <input name="thing2">
</form>
<script>
  let form;
  form = document.getElementById('thing1');
  let temp;
  temp = form.getAttribute('id');
  console.log(temp, typeof temp);
  form = document.getElementById('thing2');
  temp = form.getAttribute('id');
  console.log(temp, typeof temp);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements inside `form` are appended to its DOM object as properties, with their names as key.

You can alternatively access them like this:

```
form = document.getElementById('thing1');
input = form.querySelector('[name="id"]')
```

Comment: meaning that they overwrite the existing DOM properties ? So in the above example 'form.getAttribute('id')' continues to yield the initially assigned value (`'thing1'`), while `form.id` is `'thing1'` only if the form doesn't have a child element with `name="id"`. If it does have such a child element, `form.id` will yield the child element's `value`. Correct?

Comment: @DirkAlbrecht true